# Script only works in Python installed directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, directory, zbar

I have this script which read bar codes from images.

```
from PIL import Image
import zbar

scanner = zbar.ImageScanner()
scanner.parse_config('enable')
pil = Image.open('zbartest2.png').convert('L')
width, height = pil.size
raw = pil.tostring()
image = zbar.Image(width, height, 'Y800', raw)
scanner.scan(image)

for symbol in image:
    print 'decoded', symbol.type, 'symbol', '"%s"' % symbol.data
del(image)
```

When i put this script in python main directory which is `C:\Python27` it works without any problem.

However, when i put this script outside of main directory such as `C:\myscript`, it gives me error saying that `import zbar - module The specified module could not be found`.

What is causing the problem?

I am using Python 2.7 32bits on windows Xp 32bits SP3

EDIT:

I am executing it from the IDLE window by using run module command (F5)
;full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\myscript\test.py", line 2, in <module>
   import zbar
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

when i type in `import zbar; print zbar.__file__`
i get the following msg

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\zbar.pyd
```

Comment: What is the *full* traceback (i.e. copy/paste everything printed to the command prompt)? How are you executing this script?

Comment: What do you get if you run following command in `c:\python27`: `import zbar; print zbar.__file__` ?

Comment: Which module? What is the exact error you get?

Comment: @ChrisAung: Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit Python?

Comment: @Blender 32bit python on 32 bit windows xp sp3

Comment: _Where_ are you typing in the `import zbar; print zbar.__file__` that appears to work? IDLE's Python Shell window?

Comment: I'd try moving the `import zbar` above the `PIL import` line. If it still fails you could print `sys.path` right before the `import zbar` and make sure `C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages` is in the search list.

Comment: How you get zbar installed?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda using installer from zbar site. http://zbar.sourceforge.net/download.html

Comment: @martineau (1) i don't think moving the `import zbar` will make any difference..as `there is nothing wrong with my PIL installation`(2) i tried that already.. the path is there.. yet same error message

Comment: Moving the `import zbar` shouldn't make any difference, but it's one thing that ought be eliminated at this point when trying to systematically diagnosis your problem when other things haven't worked. It's also easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the dll is in c:\Python27 but c:\Python27 is not in the search path. Try the adding

```
import sys

sys.path.append("C:\Python2.7")
```

to your code before importing zbar.

If works correctly, then you have to configure your python's search paths in order to add C:\Python27. I work on linux, sorry I can't help you to do that on Windows.

**EDIT**: Well, I don't like write in an answer that I don't know how to do something. So I do some research looking for some doc that help me figure out what your problem is. And found it here [importing PYD files](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/154379/importing-pyd-files).

Comment: One way to manually configure Python's search path is to modify its `site.py` file in the standard library. This module is imported automatically when the Python interpreter is run (unless doing so is inhibited via a command-line switch). See [_Modifying Python’s Search Path_](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.6/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path) in the online documentation for more details.

Answer (score -3):

Make sure you have all the files that you are importing in the same directory as this script

Comment: All the imported files do not need to be the same directory as the script -- so this answer is just plain wrong.